# Selenium Grid 2 : Local hub and 2 local nodes

Tags: selenium, testng, selenium-rc, selenium-grid

Currently, I am setting up a Selenium Grid for running test suites on a hub and distribute these tests over the nodes.

The idea is to get the test executed on the hub and distributed over 10 nodes to execute them further. For the starters and evaluate the grid, I have set up a local hub and 2 local nodes.

In my test class, I have 4 tests, on running the test using RemoteDriver and passing the hub as URL and configured capabilities, it executes all four tests on Node1 and does not distribute it over to Node2. Also, it runs all 4 tests serially on Node1. Does any one know what could be wrong here. Please find the setup below.

Hub Configuration :

```
C:\Proto\Selserversidedjars>java 
    -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar 
    -role hub -hubConfig DefaultHub.json
```

Node 1 Configuration :

```
C:\Proto\Selserversidedjars>java 
    -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar  
    -role node  
    -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register
```

Node 2 Configuration :

```
C:\Proto\Selserversidedjars>java 
    -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar 
    -role node 
    -nodeConfig DefaultNode1.json 
    -port 6666
```

Defaulthub.json :

```
{
  "host": null,
  "port": 4444,
  "newSessionWaitTimeout": -1,
  "servlets" : [],
  "prioritizer": null,
  "capabilityMatcher": "org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher",
  "throwOnCapabilityNotPresent": true,
  "nodePolling": 5000,

  "cleanUpCycle": 5000,
  "timeout": 300000,
  "browserTimeout": 0,
  "maxSession": 5,
  "jettyMaxThreads":-1
}
```

DefaultNode1.json:

```
{
  "capabilities":
      [
        {
          "browserName": "*firefox",
          "maxInstances": 5,
          "seleniumProtocol": "Selenium"
        },
        {
          "browserName": "*googlechrome",
          "maxInstances": 5,
          "seleniumProtocol": "Selenium"
        },
        {
          "browserName": "*iexplore",
          "maxInstances": 1,
          "seleniumProtocol": "Selenium"
        },
        {
          "browserName": "firefox",
          "maxInstances": 5,
          "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
        },
        {
          "browserName": "chrome",
          "maxInstances": 5,
          "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
        },
        {
          "browserName": "internet explorer",
          "maxInstances": 1,
          "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
        }
      ],
  "configuration":
  {
    "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
    "maxSession": 5,
    "port": 6666,
    "host": ip,
    "register": true,
    "registerCycle": 5000,
    "hubPort": 4444,
    "hubHost": ip
  }
}
```

Now after these configuration setup, my hub is started on port 4444, node 1 is started at 5555, node 2 is started at 6666. In my TestNG tests, I am trying to execute 4 tests. Given that I have multiple tests to run in a single class, is it possible to distribute those tests over multiple nodes or multiple instances on a single node?

Any help on "how to execute multiple instances on Node1 and distribute tests(let's say more than 10 tests) over to the Node2 in this situation" will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running serially or parallely depends on how you are triggering your tests and just doesn't happen automatically just by using the grid.  Grid just helps in distributing tests over various nodes - if tests are sent serially it would distribute serially, if sent parallely, it would distribute on various nodes.

You might consider using [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-running) to run your tests parallely or you can venture to implement your own parallelism.

You mention your single class has multiple tests - with testng, you can set the parallel attribute to methods which would trigger each test in individual threads which would be sent to the grid and the hub would take care of picking up a free node and executing your test.

Take care to write threadsafe driver launch code so that each thread has it's own driver instance.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply! Can you please explain threadsafe driver launch code?

Comment: what is the difference of using the parallel ="tests" vs parallel = "methods" in the testsuite. We have before method and after method in each test class with multiple tests.

Comment: Please raise new questions, instead of in comments - helps people searching for answers.  tests stand for <test> tag in xml which can consist of any number of classes, methods etc.  Methods is each @Test method